# populating DropDownList in a gridview with array elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, gridview

I have been trying to Populate a DropDownList  in my gridview with array elements . The array consists of the column names from another gridview .The array element seems to get the column names from its source but i can not figure out how to give that to the dropdownlist.Here is my code-:

```
   public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string[] excel = new string[250];
    DataTable dtt = (DataTable)Session["griddata"];  //griddata is the gridview data from another page        
    for (int i = 0; i < dtt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        excel[i] = dtt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    }
    Session["exceldata"] = excel;
    ArrayList mylist= (ArrayList)Session["exceldata"];
    DropDownList drd = (DropDownList)GridView2.FindControl("DrdDatabase");
    drd.DataSource = mylist;
    drd.DataTextField = "GridView";
    drd.DataBind();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply loop it and add the `ListItems` programmatically:

```
DropDownList drd = (DropDownList)GridView1.FindControl("DrdDatabase");
foreach(string colName in mylist)
    drd.Items.Add(new ListItem( colName ));
```

However, are you sure that you find your `DropDownList` via `GridView1.FindControl`? I assume you get a `NullRefernceException` there. Then you need to show us where it actually is.

If it is in a `TemplateField` of the `GridView` you should use the `RowDataBound` event:

```
private ArrayList ExcelData
{
    get {
        object excel = Session["exceldata"];
        if (excel == null) Session["exceldata"] = new ArrayList();
        return (ArrayList)Session["exceldata"];
    }
    set {
        Session["exceldata"] = value;
    }
}

protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DrdDatabase");
        foreach (string colName in ExcelData)
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(colName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Tim .But there is no rowdatabound event so the gridview can't be displayed yet(since there is no data yet).Is there a way to display the dropdownlist in this gridview.

Thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: @rawatdeepesh: `RowDataBound` is triggered for every `GridViewRow` including `Header`,`Footer`,`DataRow` (repeating for every  data-row),`EmptyDataRow`, `Pager` and `Separator`. So you either have to put the dropdown in the header / footer / pager or in the  `EmptyDataTemplate`. Or don't put it into the GridView at all.

Comment: Great   Tim Schmelter. You saved my time.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. If you find an answer helpful you can vote it up ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic which you can use to populate your dropdownlist.
->

```
Loop at the array.
{
 For each item in array
   {
    add item to dropdownlist.items
   }
}
```

Sorry for not providing the exact code as I dont have .net editor at my disposal right now but you can use the logic to implement it.

regards.